# Elegant way to assign value to a column based on day interval of a group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like as given below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'subject_id' :[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'day':[3,7,9,10,11,19,20,7,13,18,22] , 'fake_flag' :['fake VAC','','fake VAC','fake VAC','fake VAC','fake VAC','fake VAC','fake VAC','fake VAC','fake VAC','fake VAC']})
```

It looks like as shown below

[image]

I would like to fill values in `actual_flag` column based on below rules

a) `fake_flag` should have a value as `fake_vac` and it shouldn't be empty

b) fill values only for 1st day when `fake_vac` appears and for records after `14 days interval`.

This is what I tried

```
t = df1[df1['fake_flag'] == 'fake VAC']
sub_list = t['subject_id'].unique().tolist()
   for sub in sub_list:
     day_list = t['day'][t['subject_id']==sub].tolist()
     min_value = min(day_list)
     index = t[t['day']==min_value].index
     df1.loc[index, 'actual_flag'] = 'act_vac'
     i_14day = min_value + 14
     day_values = [i for i in day_list if i >= i_14day]
     print("day greater than 14 are ", day_values)
     if len(day_values) > 0:
         for val in day_values:
            index = t[t['day']==val].index
            df1.loc[index, 'actual_flag'] = 'act_vac'
```

As you can see this is very lengthy and I can't do this for dataset of million records. Any efficient and elegant approach is helpful

I **expect my output** to be like as shown below

[image]

In this case for subject_id = 1, `day 3` is the 1st time when `fake vac` appears and `day 19` (19 is gt > 14 days interval from 3) and `day 20` (20 is gt > 14 days interval from 3) are after 14 days interval. Any elegant and efficient solution is helpful

**sample data for testing**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'subject_id' :[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'day':[2,3,7,9,10,11,19,20,7,13,18,22] , 'fake_flag' :['','fake VAC','','fake VAC','fake VAC','fake VAC','fake VAC','fake VAC','fake VAC','fake VAC','fake VAC','fake VAC']})
```

** updated screenshot**

[image]

Comment: I don't wish to loop over all subjects or records to do this for my dataset. It has over million records and will be very slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to subtract the first day from all dates within each group, check which are greater than `14` and set these to `"act_vac"`, as well as the initial days:

```
import numpy as np
# Returns a boolean with True if a given day - first day > 14
ix = df1.fake_flag.ne('').groupby(df1.subject_id).transform('idxmax')
c1 = df1.day.sub(df1.values[ix, 1]).gt(14)
# True if the id is different to previous row
c2 = df1.subject_id.ne(df1.subject_id.shift())
# logical OR of the above conditions
df1['actual_flag'] = np.where(c1 | c2, 'act_vac', '')

     subject_id  day fake_flag actual_flag
0            1    3  fake VAC     act_vac
1            1    7                      
2            1    9  fake VAC            
3            1   10  fake VAC            
4            1   11  fake VAC            
5            1   19  fake VAC     act_vac
6            1   20  fake VAC     act_vac
7            2    7  fake VAC     act_vac
8            2   13  fake VAC            
9            2   18  fake VAC            
10           2   22  fake VAC     act_vac
```

---

**Details**

```
df1.assign(c1=c1, c2=c2, actual_flag= np.where(c1 | c2, 'act_vac', ''))

     subject_id  day fake_flag actual_flag     c1     c2
0            1    3  fake VAC     act_vac  False   True
1            1    7                        False  False
2            1    9  fake VAC              False  False
3            1   10  fake VAC              False  False
4            1   11  fake VAC              False  False
5            1   19  fake VAC     act_vac   True  False
6            1   20  fake VAC     act_vac   True  False
7            2    7  fake VAC     act_vac  False   True
8            2   13  fake VAC              False  False
9            2   18  fake VAC              False  False
10           2   22  fake VAC     act_vac   True  False
```

Comment: would you mind helping me with this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57669326/compare-preceding-two-rows-with-subsequent-two-rows-of-each-group-till-last-reco

Comment: Do let me know though if this solved for you by accepting. I've added some more explanations @SSMK

Comment: am new to python. so i try to learn by executing line by line. will defintely update soon

Comment: Here you have considered the first day using minimum but the minimum has to be from the first day when we saw `fake_vac`. In the above example case, first day was `day 3` for subject_id = 1. We have to calculate 14 days difference from the day when `fake_vac` occurred for the first time. So `day 3` will have `act_vac` and any days after 14 days from `day 3` will have `act_vae`, like `day 18`,`day 19` etc

Comment: To help you, I have added sample data in the post at the bottom. you can try with that

Comment: If you have time, can you help me with the other post that I shared earlier? It is related to this question

Comment: Hey sorry, even after your code update, for subject_id = 1 it is giving incorrect output. `act_vac` should be at the first `fake_vac` and other records where day interval is more than 14

Comment: Please refer my screenshot in post

Comment: I think issue is with `c2`, As we shift, it's picking NaN as different which is incorrect in this scenario

Comment: Hello, Just updated this `c2 = df1.day.sub(df1.values[ix,1]).eq(0)` to get the expected output. Thanks for your help