# How to vectorize code with nested if and loops in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, vectorization, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like given below

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'subject_id' :[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    'day':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
    'PEEP' :[7,5,10,10,11,11,14,14,17,17,21,21,23,23,25,25,22,20,26,26,5,7,8,8,9,9,13,13,15,15,12,12,15,15,19,19,19,22,22,15]
})
df['fake_flag'] = ''
```

In this operation, I am performing an operation as shown below in code. This code works fine and produces expected output but I can't use this approach for a real dataset as it has more than million records.

```py
t1 = df['PEEP']
for i in t1.index:
   if i >=2:
      print("current value is  ", t1[i])
      print("preceding 1st (n-1) ", t1[i-1])
      print("preceding 2nd (n-2) ", t1[i-2])
         if (t1[i-1] == t1[i-2] or t1[i-2] >= t1[i-1]):
            r1_output = t1[i-2] # we get the max of these two values (t1[i-2]), it doesn't matter when it's constant(t1[i-2] or t1[i-1]) will have the same value anyway
            print("rule 1 output is ", r1_output)
            if t1[i] >= r1_output + 3:
                print("found a value for rule 2", t1[i])
                print("check for next value is same as current value", t1[i+1])
                if (t1[i]==t1[i+1]):
                    print("fake flag is being set")
                    df['fake_flag'][i] = 'fake_vac'
```

However, I can't apply this to real data as it has more than million records. I am learning Python and can you help me understand how to vectorize my code in Python?

You can refer this post [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57669326/compare-preceding-two-rows-with-subsequent-two-rows-of-each-group-till-last-reco) to understand the logic. As I have got the logic right, I have created this post mainly to seek help in vectorizing and fastening my code

I expect my output to be like as shown below

**subject_id = 1**

[image]

**subject_id = 2**

[image]

Is there any efficient and elegant way to fasten my code operation for a million records dataset

Comment: `t1` is the same than `df` ?

Comment: updated the post

Comment: better if you give the view of output df textual description of what you are trying to do

Comment: updated the post @AkashKumar

Comment: What is the logic for giving a value of `'fake VAC'` in the `5th` column? I think `numpy.where()` can be used here.

Comment: Okay, can you look at this related post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57669326/compare-preceding-two-rows-with-subsequent-two-rows-of-each-group-till-last-reco

Comment: I created this post to kind of fasten the code operation/working. However my other linked post has no accepted answer. If you can help, it would be great

Comment: The upvoted answer in that post, used as predicted the `np.where` method. Does it not work in your problem?

Comment: No, it doesn't give the expected answer. would you be able to help me by improving it?

Comment: Both the answers below were helpful and helped me with this problem. However I chose @Mark Wang answer as solution because it was very simple to understand. Nonetheless Scott's answer was also good to know and helpful.

Comment: Can you guys help me with this related post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57703423/how-to-get-minimum-of-each-group-for-each-day-based-on-hour-criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what's the story behind this, but you can certainly vectorize three `if` independently and combine them together,

```
con1 = t1.shift(2).ge(t1.shift(1))
con2 = t1.ge(t1.shift(2).add(3))
con3 = t1.eq(t1.shift(-1))

df['fake_flag']=np.where(con1 & con2 & con3,'fake VAC','')
```

**Edit (Groupby SubjectID)**

```
con = lambda x: (x.shift(2).ge(x.shift(1))) & (x.ge(x.shift(2).add(3))) & (x.eq(x.shift(-1)))

df['fake_flag'] = df.groupby('subject_id')['PEEP'].transform(con).map({True:'fake VAC',False:''})
```

Comment: Wow, awesome. didn't know that it could be this simple. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: I think you need to apply a groupby also to prevent subject1 and subject 2 commingling.

Comment: @Mark Wang - Would you mind updating your answer with groupby to be useful for others as well? Yes, we need based on each subject_id

Comment: Thank you for the help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @ Mark Wang, Can you let me know how can I check similar check on another column? Right now, we have applied this to only one column. If in the same `con` statement, I would like to include another column condition (`con4`), how can I do it?

Comment: slightly different. See if you can pick up the differeces..`con = lambda x:(x['PEEP'].shift(2).ge(x['PEEP'].shift(1))) & (x['PEEP'].ge(x['PEEP'].shift(2).add(3))) & (x['PEEP2'].eq(x['PEEP2'].shift(-1)))` , `df['fake_flag'] = df.groupby('subject_id').apply(con).map({True:'fake VAC',False:''}).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)`

Comment: Hello @MarkWang - Can you see this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57695288/how-to-include-two-lambda-operations-in-transform-function

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
df.groupby('subject_id')\
  .rolling(3)['PEEP'].apply(lambda x: (x[-1] - x[:2].max()) >= 3, raw=True).fillna(0).astype(bool)
```

Output:

```
subject_id    
1           0     False
            1     False
            2      True
            3     False
            4     False
            5     False
            6      True
            7     False
            8      True
            9     False
            10     True
            11    False
            12    False
            13    False
            14    False
            15    False
            16    False
            17    False
            18     True
            19    False
2           20    False
            21    False
            22    False
            23    False
            24    False
            25    False
            26     True
            27    False
            28    False
            29    False
            30    False
            31    False
            32     True
            33    False
            34     True
            35    False
            36    False
            37     True
            38    False
            39    False
Name: PEEP, dtype: bool
```

#### Details:

- Use `groupby` to break the data up using 'subject_id'
- Apply `rolling` with a n=3 or a window size three.
- Look at that last value in that window using -1 indexing and subtact
  the maximum of the first two values in that window using index
  slicing.

Comment: Wow, you are awesome. Would you mind giving some details for a beginner like me. I guess it is working. I am able to see `True` in all right places

Comment: If you could break it down, I can execute piece by piece to actually understand and then apply for different data(real data)

Comment: You group by subject id, then using rolling with a window of three values... Take the last value in that window  and subtract if from that maximum of the first two values in the window.  Check to see if greater than 3.

Comment: But you also have to check for next value (`n+1`). You take `n` and check with `n-1` and `n-2` and then also make sure `n` and `n+1` are identical

Comment: If you see my output screenshot, you will get an idea and I hope that will help