# How to include two lambda operations in transform function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as given below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'date' :['2173-04-03 12:35:00','2173-04-03 17:00:00','2173-04-03 20:00:00','2173-04-04 11:00:00','2173-04-04 12:00:00','2173-04-04 11:30:00','2173-04-04 16:00:00','2173-04-04 22:00:00','2173-04-05 04:00:00'],
'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
'val' :[5,5,5,10,10,5,5,8,8]
 })
```

I would like to apply couple of logic (`logic_1` on `val` column and `logic_2` on `date` column) to the code. Please find below the logic

```
logic_1 = lambda x: (x.shift(2).ge(x.shift(1))) & (x.ge(x.shift(2).add(3))) & (x.eq(x.shift(-1)))
logic_2 = lambda y: (y.shift(1).ge(1)) & (y.shift(2).ge(2)) & (y.shift(-1).ge(1))
```

credit to SO users for helping me with logic

This is what I tried below

```
   df['label'] = ''
   df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
   df['tdiff'] = df['date'].shift(-1) - df['date']
   df['tdiff'] = df['tdiff'].dt.total_seconds()/3600
   df['lo_1'] = df.groupby('subject_id')['val'].transform(logic_1).map({True:'1',False:''})
   df['lo_2'] = df.groupby('subject_id')['tdiff'].transform(logic_2).map({True:'1',False:''})
```

How can I make both the `logic_1` and `logic_2` be part of one logic statement? Is it even possible? I might have more than 2 logics as well. Instead of writing one line for each logic, is it possible to couple all logics together in one logic statement.

I expect my output to be with `label` column being filled with `1` when both `logic_1` and `logic_2` are satisfied

[image]

Comment: You can do this:

 df['lo_1'] = df.groupby('subject_id')['val'].transform(lambda x: function(x)).map({True:'1',False:''})

and the you have a def function(x): with both logics

Comment: But, we have `val` column for `logic_1` and `tdiff` column for `logic_2`. In your answer, you are using `val` column

Comment: You mean,  `df.groupby('subject_id')['val'].transform(logic_1) & df.groupby('subject_id')['tdiff'].transform(logic_2)`?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: That's the answer..

Comment: You men, the one from other post? If you can put it here, I can mark it as answer

Comment: Will try your suggestion

Comment: Don't assign lambda expressions to variables; use a `def` statement.

Comment: Can you write as an answer @chepner

Comment: @MarkWang - You mean to say that we can't get away with groupby statements. Since we have two columns, 2 groupby is necessary?

Comment: I'm saying if you need to apply condition based on two columns, you may need groupby.apply instead of transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few things to fix
First, in `logic_2`, you have `lambda x` but use `y`, so, you got to change that as below

```
logic_2 = lambda y: (y.shift(1).ge(1)) & (y.shift(2).ge(2)) & (y.shift(-1).ge(1))
```

Then you can use the logic's together as below'
No need to create a blank column `label`. You can create the '`label' column directly as below.

```
df['label'] = ((df.groupby('subject_id')['val'].transform(logic_1))
           & (df.groupby('subject_id')['tdiff'].transform(logic_2))).map({True:'0',False:'1'})
```

Note: You logic produces all `False` values. So, you will get 1's if `False` is mapped to 1, not `True`

Comment: If I have 10 logics for 10 columns in my real data, do I have to use 10 groupby statements?

Comment: Unfortunately, i think yes. But if you put the question, we can see if we can accomplish it with just one `def`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.what question?

Comment: for the question where you asked "If I have 10 logics for 10 columns in my real data, do I have to use 10 groupby statements?" , my answer is "Unfortunately, i think yes. But if you put a new question with the result & the logic to get that result, we can see if we can accomplish it with just one"

Comment: okay, for logic_1 refer this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676327/how-to-vectorize-code-with-nested-if-and-loops-in-python

Comment: for logic_2, it just that `tdiff` should be >= 1. If you refer my output screenshot example, you will understand

Comment: logic 2 is nothing but diff between `n-1` and `n` should be >=1 and diff between `n-2` and `n` should be >= 2 and difference between `n` and `n+1` should be >= 1. Hope this helps

Comment: I did not get the logic. Instead of explaining with numbers, please explain what you are trying to do. For example, you can say, within each day, if the value doubles , then the whole day should get a value of 1 in column `label` or something like that (i just made this up now). Since it takes quite a bit of explanation, i would say a different question is better.

Comment: You can push several columns to do the lambda function, and then, inside the function, separate the columns to perform the individual logic column by column like:
df.groupby('subject_id')['val', 'tdiff', 'colum3', 'column4'.., 'colum10'].transform(logic_1)

Comment: Can you giys help me with this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57703423/how-to-get-minimum-of-each-group-for-each-day-based-on-hour-criteria. It is related post